# RaiseEvent not being handled

Tags: vb.net, events

I have made a custom event. What I intend to do is make a custom task pane invisible when I click the close button however it doesn't run my `MainTaskPaneControl_HideTaskPane` method. I'm clearly missing something simple but I'm unsure what I'm missing.

Code that runs first in ThisAddIn class:

```
Dim gen = New PowerPointDocSetUpMain()
AddHandler gen.HideTaskPane, AddressOf MainTaskPaneControl_HideTaskPane
```

Cancel Button in PowerPointDocSetUp class:

```
Private Sub ButtonCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCancel.Click
    Dim main As PowerPointDocSetUpMain = New PowerPointDocSetUpMain
    main.CloseMain()
End Sub
```

PowerPointDocSetUpMain class:

```
Public Event HideTaskPane()
Public Function CloseMain()
    RaiseEvent HideTaskPane()

End Function
```

MainTaskPaneControl_HideTaskPane method in ThisAddIn class:

```
Friend Sub MainTaskPaneControl_HideTaskPane()
    'Hide the requested task pane.
    Globals.ThisAddIn.HideTaskPane()
End Sub
```

HideTaskPane method in ThisAddIn class:

```
Friend Function HideTaskPane() As System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
    myTaskPane.Visible = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two code snippets there that create `PowerPointDocSetUpMain` objects, so you're creating two different objects. One of them you register an event handler on and the other one you call `CloseMain` on. The one you call the method on has no event handler and the one with an event handler doesn't have the method called on it. It's hard to know what the exact solution should be because we don't really know how those code snippets relate to each other but the first two code snippets can't both create new objects. If the first one creates an object and registers an event handler then the second one must call `CloseMain` on that same object.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand what you are saying and it is correct but I'm not sure how I would fix this as I need an instance of `PowerPointDocSetUpMain` for my cancel button

Comment: Like I said, it's hard to be specific because we don't know the relationship between those code snippets. Basically though, the second code snippet needs to refer to the object created in the first code snippet. That means that you need to put that object somewhere that the second code snippet can access it, i.e. the `ThisAddIn` object that creates the `PowerPointDocSetUpMain` object and registers the event handler needs to pass it into the `PowerPointDocSetUp` object that calls `CloseMain`.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the Handler to the object `gen` here:

```
AddHandler gen.HideTaskPane, AddressOf MainTaskPaneControl_HideTaskPane
```

But in the `Button_Click`-method a new object `main` is created without adding a Handler to it. So the Handler for `gen` is never being called and the one for `main` does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand what you are saying but I'm not sure how I would fix this as I need an instance of `PowerPointDocSetUpMain` for my cancel button